# NUnit doesn´t run my new Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

My new tests in NUnit appears in Tests List in a blue font. And I can´t run it.

This is que list.
[image]

And this is my class. I can´t find anything wrong or even diferent from other test classes.

[image]

Please! Do someone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to decorate the testfixture with a category that is included in your nunit console? Also, no harm to make the test fixture class public.

Answer (score 9):

Your test fixture class is not `public`. If you don't specify `public class YouClass`, YourClass will be `internal`, and not runnable by NUnit.

Answer (score 3):

Last I used NUnit your test classes needed to be public. Your `EmailBaseGerar` doesn't specify that it is public, and is getting [defaulted to internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).